# How to check type of type parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I need to check type of generic.

In type alias, I can do this:

```js
type Obj<J, T> = J extends number ? {
    [x: number]: T
}: J extends string ? {
    [x: string]: T
}: never;
```

But in class, I can’t:

```js
class List<T = any> {
   private IsNumbered = T extends number;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: this is because in the first case you deal with type inference (types on the left, and types on the right) 
but in the second case, you try to compute the initial value of the private filed form the type. It is a mixture of contexts

Comment: What kind of type check do you expect for ```IsNumbered```? ```extends``` keyword in TS can be used in one of two cases: generic type variables constraints and conditional types. Check the documentation for use cases and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you try to mix types and runtime values. TS has no reflection API, so it is not possible to use types to compute runtime values.
To highlight this idea your example could be refactored as follows:

```
class Foo<T = any> {
   T value;
   get IsNumbered() {
       return typeof this.value === 'number';
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it is `value: T`